# strange error from MP _playbackInterruptionDidEndNotification

Tags: objective-c

Does any body have any idea what this console output means?

I'm using 4.3.3 SDK on xcode 4.0.2 on snow leopard

and every so often whilst recording video or playing back

I get this message in the console

```
MP _playbackInterruptionDidEndNotification :: NSConcreteNotification 0x6402a80 {name = AVController_PlaybackInterruptionDidEndNotification; object = <AVController: 0x64a35f0>; userInfo = {
"AVController_InterruptionStatusNotificationParameter" = "non-resumable.SoloAmbientSound";
"AVController_InterruptorNameNotificationParameter" = "AudioSession-2113";
```

if anyone can shed some light as to what it means or how to get rid of it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using a multitask gesture (4 finger swipe) with an instance of MPMoviePlayerViewController open in fullScreen.  This caused the app to crash hard, disabling the iPad from rotating and killing the iPad eventually.

It appears that the cause of this is largely due to not having your .plist file set up properly.

1. Open your .plist file and find the key "Required background modes" (if you are showing the raw key values, it's is called "UIBackgroundModes").
2. Open the dropdown for "Required background modes" and click into "Item 0" (or add a new row there)
3. In the "Value" column, enter "App plays audio" (you can see it in the dropdown menu if you click the arrows by the add row plus sign

Once you do that, you shouldn't receive that error again.

//EDIT
As long as the app doesn't need to play the video and audio while you're somewhere else in your app or another app, you probably don't want to keep that video streaming and eating those resources.  So add and check that "Application does not run in background" box in your .plist.

As for the playback, there are a lot of thinks that can happen during playback that can crash the app and device.  Add this method before the method that opens your MPMoviePlayerController:

```
- (void) moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification {
if (movplayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) {
    [movplayer setContentURL:[movplayer contentURL]];
    [movplayer play];
}
}
```

Then add this observer in the method that calls your MPMoviePlayerController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

This will catch a change, like the video player finishing, or fast forwarding to the end of the video, and reset the video to the beginning if iOS doesn't like something.  It's helpful to manage these kind of errors/crashes that happen with the player.

Comment: I checked my .plist file and did not find the Required background modes in there..So I added one and hoped that it would work, unfortunately it is still there

Comment: you can also try adding "Application does not run in background" to the .plist and check the box

Comment: can you explain the few actions that lead to you getting this error in the console?

Comment: my app can record video as well as play it back..I usually get this error after a video has finished playing and the app is sent to background.. eg: i hit the home button..so app is in background, but video had already finished playing..when app comes into foreground...this sometimes shows the error message...the problem is, it doesn't do it everytime, so I can't really trace it

Comment: check the edit to my original answer...one or both of those solutions should help your cause.

Comment: hey thanks for that...putting in the application does not run in background to TRUE seems to have done the trick. but does this mean then that every time home button is press..my app will always be exited, rather than suspended? please confirm...thanks

Comment: for the most part yes...do you really want your user to be able to play videos/audio when your app is suspended?  It might be a cool feature for some apps, but if you're focusing on recording and playing back, and you're not multithreading, it doesn't sound like you need to have anything running in the background.

Comment: have you moved on or found another solution?

Comment: I haven't moved on as yet..and no, I've not found another solution, your solution works, but for my app, I run an update check on contacts when app enters background, which never gets called now...I am hoping for another solution if it exists..??